# Showing a component only after the data for it's viewmodel has loaded

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5, extjs6

I have a method on my controller that fires when a grid in my app is itemclicked.

When the grid row is clicked, I create a new instance of a details window widget, grab it's viewmodel, and create a link. After this link is created I show the window:

```
...
itemClicked: function (item, record, index, event, eOpts){

    var detailsWindow = Ext.widget('sessiondetails'),
        viewmodel = detailsWindow.getViewModel();


    viewmodel.linkTo('sessiondetails', {
        reference: 'Registration.model.SessionDetails',
        id: record.id
    });
    detailsWindow.show();
}
...
```

The model class that is referenced in the linkTo method call has a rest proxy config, so when the linkTo is fired, a GET request is made for the data:

```
Ext.define('Registration.model.SessionDetails', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        ...
    ],
    proxy:{
        type: 'rest',
        url: 'sessions',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'record'
        }
    }
});
```

This all works great. The thing I'm trying to figure out is how to hide or at least mask the window widget until the record has actually loaded.

Right now, the window appears, there's a second or two delay, and then the data appears once the result from the GET request is returned.

I would prefer to be able to show the window masked and then unmask it once the data has loaded. I know I can use the `.mask()` method after showing the window:

```
...
detailsWindow.show();
detailsWindow.mask('Loading...');
```

But I can't figure out how to remove the mask after the ViewModel has finished loading the record.

How would I do this? Am I approaching it wrong?

## Update: The Fix

Based on the second option in the answer by Robert Watkins, I refactored my code to:

- Show and mask the window immediately
- Load the record directly from the model
- In the success callback for the load method

  - Set the returned data into the ViewModel
  - Unmask the window

Here's the updated method:

```
itemClicked: function (item, record, index, event, eOpts){

    // create the window
    var detailsWindow = Ext.widget('sessiondetails');

    // Get an instance of the model class
    var model = Registration.model.SessionDetails;

    // manually load the record
    // Note that this would be the same as firing
    // Registraton.model.SessionDetails.load(...), 
    // I just think it reads better this way
    model.load(record.id, {

        // Make sure you include the `scope: this` config, 
        // otherwise you won't have access to the 
        // previously defined `detailswindow` variable
        scope: this,
        success: function (session){
            var viewmodel = detailsWindow.getViewModel();
            viewmodel.setData(session.getData());

            // Since this callback fires after the data is returned,
            // placing the unmask here makes sure the data is loaded first.
            detailsWindow.unmask();

        }
    });

    // Show and mask the window
    detailsWindow.show();
    detailsWindow.mask('Loading...');
}
```

Comment: Can you use routing? You could configure a before in the route, and resume the action when the success of the load function on the model is called. In the 'normal' route function you display the window using the id (which is a parameter of the hash of the route).

Comment: Hmm, I follow the logic you're outlining, but I'm still a bit green to sencha when it comes to figuring out how that would apply within my project. I'll explore a bit and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/application_architecture/router.html

Comment: Oh! My bad, I do know the router. For some reason I was thinking it was something else. Thank's for the link. I'll consider if what I have now would be better refactored via the code used to route to a particular session (which is a good idea).

Comment: It's all up to you. You have to maintain the code. Here another article about routing and user sessions: https://sencha.guru/2015/07/02/handling-user-session-with-routes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a binding of your own:

`this.maskBinding = this.getViewModel().bind({
    bindTo: 'sessiondetails', 
    single: true,
  }, function() { detailsWindow.unmask(); })`

The binding will call the provided function when the bound value (the `sessiondetails` value) changes. This should be called when the record is loaded.

(NB: I haven't tried this particular approach, but I have used bindings before to detect changes to values).

The fallback would be for you to load the model explicitly, and then bind the value to the view model and remove the mask as part of the success response to loading the model.

Comment: I tried the bind in your answer's first part. It worked as far as applying the mask, but the callback must happen after the `sessiondetails` value is created but before the data population of the window items. You see the mask flash for a split second and then it unmasks before the data loads. I'm about to try the second option now to see how it goes.

Comment: Second option worked. I'll update my answer with the code I used to help illustrate. Thanks!!